# Grafana 6.7 auth proxy behind nginx for automatic UI login

Tags: nginx, grafana, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Nginx reverse proxy in front of my Grafana server.

I'm trying to use Nginx `auth_basic` to automatically login the user into Grafana.

I would like to do this, to be able to automatically login an embedded iframe graph placed in another web application (not on the same network)

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    server_name grafana.mydomain.com;
    ...
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://grafana.mydomain.com;
    }
    location /grafana/ {
            proxy_pass http://grafana.mydomain.com;
            auth_basic      "Restricted grafana.mydomain.com";
            auth_basic_user_file    /etc/nginx/htpasswd/grafana.mydomain.com;
            proxy_set_header X-WEBAUTH-USER $remote_user;
            proxy_set_header Authorization "";
    }
}
```

**grafana.ini**

```
[auth.basic]
enabled = true

[security]
allow_embedding = true
cookie_samesite = lax
root_url = https://grafana.mydomain.com/grafana/

[auth.proxy]
enabled = true
header_name = X-WEBAUTH-USER
header_property = username
auto_sign_up = true
sync_ttl = 60
enable_login_token = true
```

What is happening with this setup, is that if I go to `grafana.mydomain.com` it appears the normal login and everything works fine
While if I go to `grafana.mydomain.com/grafana/` after logging in with Nginx, Grafana return this:
[image]

If I try to click on any link on the page a lot of unauthorized errors appears and I get logged out.

I've been playing with those settings a lot:

- proxy_set_header X-WEBAUTH-USER
- root_url
- enable_login_token
- cookie_samesite

But was unable to make things working

The user is created inside Grafana, so I have tried to give the created user full permissions:
[image]

But I still get unauthorized errors and 404 errors

I'm not even sure this is the right path to achieve what I'm trying to do, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the two locations and placed the authentication for the `/` location
Then I've switched back `cookie_samesite = none` and it started working as it was supposed to do.

By doing this I lost the possibility to log into grafana normally

Comment: I have recently had to do the same. Ultimately the best solution for me was to use Treafik to setup two routes. One injecting the Header, the Other passing straight through to grafana.